# Do I run pod update after react-native link with react-native-image-picker?

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios, react-native-linking

I'm following the instructions for React Native Image Picker and I'm confused about whether I should run `pod install` after `react-native link`

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker#install

From what I can tell it adds this line to the podfile

```
pod 'react-native-image-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker
```

It doesn't seem to link anything else in the iOS Xcode project or hook up or link anything else in the xcode project.

Calling ImagePicker in the react native code gives the runtime error

```
cannot read property 'showImagePicker' of undefined error when calling ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options)
```

ImagePicker and showImagePicker is defined in the javascript runtime so I think the error is coming from the ios side of things.

As an alternative, I tried to run pod install afterwards and I get a build error with header not found for react libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have two options, either use react-native link or use cocoapods. `react-native link` will link the framework to both IOS and Android. If you decide to use cocoapods it's only for IOS.

Comment: I ran react-native link and it only added the pod file entry  but didn't seem to do anything else to the project and errors when trying to call the method. `Runtime error, got cannot read property 'showImagePicker' of undefined error when calling ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options)`

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey don't run `pod install`, follow the manual installation process.